# Twig: passing file path as argument to url

Tags: php, symfony

I want to make files downloadble on click, but it does not work. Here comes my code:

**files.html.twig**

```
{% set filepath = asset('bundles/example/files/filename.pdf') %}
<a href="{{ url('_bundle_route_to_download', { 'filepath': filepath }) }}">
<button class="button button-icon button-download">Download</button></a>
```

**controller.php**

```
 /**
    * @Route("/example/download/{filepath}", name="_bundle_route_to_download")
    */
    public function downloadFile($filepath)
    {
      //...
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
No route found for "GET    /example/download//bundles/example/files/filename.pdf%3F1418390151
```

What is wrong about my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Syntax is not wrong, but Symfony2 Routing is looking for a route that does not exist. You need to url_encode your parameter.

The Symfony2 Routing is looking for a URL matching `/example/download//bundles/example/files/` which will not be found.

```
{% set filepath = (asset('bundles/example/files/filename.pdf'))|url_encode %}
<a href="{{ url('_bundle_route_to_download', { 'filepath': filepath }) }}">
<button class="button button-icon button-download">Download</button></a>
```

It is untested but should be doing the trick.

For more Information, see [Twig Url Encode](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html)

Though I'd not recommend to pass it through as a parameter ... -> that's how you would do that.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html) from The Cookbook to enable "/" character in route.